# Android UI (Text and icon center in layout)

Tags: android, android-studio

[image][image]

Hi,i need little bit help, need to show Shop name and share icon in Centre. I am unable to handle it properly shop. Shop name can be 3 character or max 2 lines. If 2 lines then show share icon top right corner.
also in case 2 lines there is spacing issue icon not adjacent.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/llShare"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_88sdp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStore"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ivShare"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        style="@style/poppins_semibold"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGray900"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_9sdp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        tools:text="Ashkanani" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivShare"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_share_arrow_png"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvStore"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_12sdp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share a piece of code that shows which process is having the problem?

Comment: Use constraint layout as parent for shop name and share icon.
set top and start constraints of share icon according to shop name and end constraint to parent don't attach bottom constraint of share icon to any view.

Comment: @UzairMughal can you share please of code please.

Comment: @RashidAli check my answer

Comment: @UzairMughal thanks for effort, but same issue still, image is showing in end
xml and out image added

Answer (score 0):

Consider textview as your shopname and imageview as share icon
Textview is limited to 2 lines with end elipse size

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/iv_closeBottomSheet"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="sakjdak alkdalksldaalkdalkslda alskdlak alsdklask"
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_closeBottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvTitle"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llShare"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_3sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="@dimen/_67sdp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        style="@style/poppins_semibold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_9sdp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        tools:text="Ashkanani" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivShare"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_12sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_share_arrow_png"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_1sdp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvStore"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_12sdp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set android:maxWidth="" and
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
in main layout